# how to split records with non-standard delimiters

Tags: python, data-analysis, data-import

in my csv file I have the following records separated by a , between brackets:

```
(a1,a2,a3),(b1,b2,b3),(c1,c2,c3),(d1,d2,d3)
```

How do I split the data into a list so that I get something more like this:

```
a1,a2,a3
b1,b2,b3
c1,c2,c3
d1,d2,d3
```

Currently my python code looks like this:

```
dump = open('sample_dump.csv','r').read()
splitdump = dump.split('\n')
print splitdump
```

Comment: so you want a1,a2,a3 as a single item of a list or 3 separate items

Answer (score 0):

You could do something along the lines of:

- Remove first and last brackets
- Split by `),(` character sequence

To split by a custom string, just add it as a parameter to the split method, e.g.:

```
line.split("),(")
```

It's a bit hacky, so you'll have to generalize based on any expected variations in your input data format (e.g. will your first/last chars always be brackets?).

Answer (score 0):

Try this, split first by `"),"`  then, join and split again by `(` to left tuples without brackets

```
_line = dump.split("),")
_line = ''.join(_line).split("(")
print _line
>> ['', 'a1,a2,a3,', 'b1,b2,b3,', 'c1,c2,c3,', 'd1,d2,d3']
#drop first empty element
print _line.pop(0)
>> ['a1,a2,a3,', 'b1,b2,b3,', 'c1,c2,c3,', 'd1,d2,d3']
```

Answer (score 0):

First you need to the steps you need to perform in order to get your result, here's a hacky solution:

- remove first and last brackets
- use the `),(` as the group separator, split
- split each group by `,`

> line = '(a1,a2,a3),(b1,b2,b3),(c1,c2,c3),(d1,d2,d3)'
>
> [group.split(',') for group in line[1:-1].split('),(')]